# Odoo different workflow on condition

Tags: forms, python-2.7, view, odoo, odoo-9

In my module I have states:

```
_STATES = [
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('to_approve_first', 'Waiting for approval'),
    ('approved', 'Approved'),
    ('purchase_conditions','Purchase conditions'),
    ('create_order','Creating Order'),
    ('to_approve_second','Approved'),
    ('in_stock','Products in stock'),
    ('rejected', 'Rejected')
]
```

Can I have 2 different workflows based on condition on draft state in form view? For example `if field iam_in boolean in draft state is true` worklow will be:

```
                <header>
                    <button name="%(action_sale_order_reset)d" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in', ('to_approve_first'))]}" string="Reset" type="action" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_to_approve_first" states="draft" string="Request approval" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="button_approved" states="to_approve_first" string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_purchase_conditions" states="approved" string="Return Request" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_create_order" states="purchase_conditions" string="Create Order" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_user"/>
                    <button name="button_to_approve_second" states="create_order" string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_in_stock" states="to_approve_second" string="Done" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_rejected" states="draft,purchase_conditions" string="Reject" type="object" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_user"/>
                    <button name="%(action_sale_order_cancel)d" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in', ('to_approve_first', 'approved', 'create_order'))]}" string="Cancel with feedback" type="action" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,to_approve_first,approved,rejected" statusbar_colors="{&quot;approved&quot;:&quot;green&quot;}"/>
            </header>
```

And if `iam_in boolean in draft is false` the workflow will be shorter:

```
draft -> to_approve_first -> in_stock
```

How can I do that? I was thinking about two different views. Because in views I can't use `if .. else` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use your field `iam_in` in `attrs` (invisible) to show or hide buttons. It could be a bit complex but should work, for example in your button `button_approved`:

```xml
<button name="button_approved" states="to_approve_first"
    string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight"
    groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"
    attrs="{'invisible': [('iam_in', '=', True)]}" />
```

That will only show the button if the state is `to_approve_first` and `iam_in=True`. Requirements: The field `iam_in` has to be on the model and  defined in the view, too (invisible is enough).

Care using `states` in combination with `attrs` (invisible), because both will be combinated automatically.

Comment: But I still can't write condition like this for example button "button_approved" is invisible when 'state','!=', 'to_approve_second' or invisible when 'state','!=', 'approved' and 'iam_in','=', True. Is it a possibility to write  or and state in one attrs field?

Comment: I tried: attrs="{'invisible': ['&', 'I',('state','!=', 'approved'),('participate_process','=', True)('state','!=', 'to_approve_second')]}" But I got an error that '&' symbol is unknownable symbol.